# passing a parameter into a subquery

Tags: sql

i was wondering if it is possible to pass a parameter into a select subquery.

What i want to do is collect some product data from one table and then crossref the weight of the item to it's carriage cost in a shipping table to return a cost.

something like:

```
select cataloguenumber, productname, 
      (select shipping.carriagecost 
       from shipping 
       where shipping.carriageweight = weight) as carriagecost
from products
```

Regards

DPERROTT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select cataloguenumber, productname,  shipping.carriagecost as carriagecost 
from products, shipping 
where shipping.carriageweight = products.weight
```

or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

While the subquery would work, a better, more readable and efficient way to define this would be as follows:

```
SELECT  p.cataloguenumber
 ,      p.productname,  
 ,      s.carriagecost    
FROM    products p
    INNER JOIN
        shipping s
    ON  p.weight = s.carriageweight
```

This assumes that all product weights have a corresponding entry in the shipping table. If that is not the case then change from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and deal with any nulls.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cataloguenumber, productname, shipping.carriagecost 
FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN shipping 
ON shipping.carriageweight = products.weight
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery should only return 1 row, if it returns more then that your query will throw an error in run-time.

Comment: Hi Numenor, the query would only retrieve one value as the carriage would have a specific value. i.e weight 1 = carriage 4.99

Comment: i also agree with join approach because it will run quicker then subquery in scenarios where tables have many many rows

Answer (score 0):

This is possible I think, but then you should retrieve the column you want to pass in your parent query.

```
select cataloguenumber, productname, weight 
      (select shipping.carriagecost 
       from shipping 
       where shipping.carriageweight = weight) as carriagecost
from products
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.cataloguenumber, products.productname, shipping.carriagecost 
FROM products
LEFT JOIN shipping ON shipping.carriageweight = products.weight
```